# node.js & moment : different results based on how value is passed?

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I get different output based on how values are passed to `moment`. How are they different?

```
var moment = require('moment');
var aa = "1392018037000";
var bb = "1392057925366";
console.log(moment(aa).from(bb));
console.log(moment(1392018037000).from(1392057925366));

output:
a few seconds ago
11 hours ago
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a string:

```
var aa = "1392018037000";
```

This is an integer:

```
var aa = 1392018037000;
```

According to moment documentation:

> Similar to new Date(Number), you can create a moment by passing an
>   integer value representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix
>   Epoch (Jan 1 1970 12AM UTC).

So proper way would be to use an integer. String behaves differently in Javascript, mostly because it would need to call parseInt function, and that has different way of parsing integers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt